# Which animals are recommended to be kept at home? (Shia view)

Tags: animals

As much as I know/researched, there does seem to be a kind of animals who ought not to be kept at home, on the the other hand, according to my study, if I'm not mistaken, there are some animals whose attendance at home can make blessing for the home (and its members), such as according to a hadith from Imam Ali (a.s.):

> Flapping (the wings) of pigeon reject the Shaitans.

Well, I was wondering what animals/birds shall be kept at home (apart from pigeon) -- as an Islamic recommended practice -- according to Shia view.

**Note:** I'm not looking for what animals are allowed to be kept, whereas I'm looking for: as a Mustahab (recommended) act, which animals/birds should be kept at home (whose attendance can have positive effect/blessing for home and its members.

Answer (score 1):

In order to elucidate the issue, I’d better submit some related narrations.

Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him and his family) said:

> Being sheep at home is caused that 70 doors of poverty to be removed.

Meanwhile, the Prophet said that: being sheep at home will be (is) the cause of Barakah (blessing), likewise, being cat at home causes bless… He also mentioned about the barekah(s) and actually advantages of rooster.

And so forth.

---

**Source:**

- [www.yjc.ir](http://www.yjc.ir/fa/news/5555888/%D8%B3%D9%87-%D8%AD%DB%8C%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C-%DA%A9%D9%87-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B5-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B5%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D9%86%DA%AF%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D8%A2%D9%86%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7-%DA%A9%D8%B1%D8%AF-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%AC%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%AD%D9%82%D9%88%D9%82-%D8%AD%DB%8C%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85)

Comment: Hazrat Muhammad Mustafa SAW used to call one of his sahaba with title of **Abu Hurera**, _Hurera_ is Arabic word which means _Kittens_, so meaning of that title is **Father of Kitten** because that sahaba used to come to Hazrat Muhammad Mustafa SAW with kittens.